# С прописной или строчной буквы пишется слово "совет"

Tags: прописная-строчная

1. «На основе региональных типологий, разрабатываемых в совете по изучению производительных сил, выделяются....»
2. Во главе стоит государственный экономический совет";
3. Предприятие, кооператив могут вступать в несколько таких союзов (например, по производству молока, овощей), а управление в любой из форм должно строиться только на демократических началах (собрание представителей, Совет (правление));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из словаря:

**СОВЕТ**, 1. **Высказанное  предложение, мнение**, как поступить. Хороший, полезный, дельный, своевременный с. 2. **Совместное обсуждение** чего-л.; Семейный с. Собрать, созвать с. Держать с.  3. **Представительный орган власти;** одна из форм организации общества. С. профессиональных союзов. Учёный совет института. Сельский совет. Верховный С. СССР.

Слово "совет" со значением управляющего органа, в отличие от слов "правление, собрание", **сложно использовать как нарицательное существительное**, поэтому оно обычно входит в состав имени собственного или является именем собственным, а имя собственное должно  выделяться в тексте (прописная буква, кавычки).

Решение

1) «На основе региональных типологий, разрабатываемых в **Совете по изучению производительных сил**, выделяются...

2) Во главе стоит **Государственный экономический совет.**

3) Предприятие, кооператив могут вступать в несколько таких союзов (например, по производству молока, овощей), а управление в любой из форм должно строиться только на демократических началах (собрание представителей, **Совет** (правление)).